# How can I store only the date portion of the datetime. Today property to a SQL Server table datetime column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, linq-to-sql

I am trying to update a `datetime` column in a SQL Server 2012 table by using

```
newItem.DateSaved = DateTime.Today;
```

I want to save only the `Date` part of `DateTime`, but when I am checking in the table I can see that it saves also the time part: `2018-07-27 00:00:00.000` .
How I can make it to store only `date` part? `2018-07-27` ?

**Edit**

Because my column is `datetime`, I see that I can't store only the date part. But how I can show to the user only the date part without time? Here is the select part of the Linq-to-SQL query:

```
select new { Date = smv.DateSaved.Value.Date }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Since it is DateTime, it will always have a time element.  Display only the Date portion to the user if you dont need the Time

Comment: DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d");

Comment: Set column type to `Date`

Comment: Your sql type for the column is datetime so it wants to satisfy that and thus time portion is defaulted to all zeros. If you do not want the time portion, change it to `date`.

Comment: @Plutonix please check edited post

Comment: @aggicd how you display something has to do with the UI, not the query. Set the appropriate format string in the control, HTML tag, display attribute or data binding you use.

Answer (score 5):

A `datetime` column always *has* a time part - just, in your case it will all be zeros. A `datatime` is just a number under the hood; it doesn't have any choice about what it has / doesn't have; similarly, it doesn't have any notion of formatting until your code tries to display it, and then it is the *dispalying* code that chooses the format.

If you don't want a time part, use `date` instead of `datetime` for your column.

Answer (score 4):

Change column type in SQL Server from `datetime` to `date` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store only the date without time in SQL Server database you can set the column type to `date`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN DateSaved date;
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

If you have a `DateTime` property in your model and you want to show only the date part just format it in your control in the View. For example:

```
$"{newItem.DateSaved:yyyy-MM-dd}"
```

or

```
newItem.DateSaved.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

You can also use `"d"` or `"D"` (short and long version) instead of specific format like `"yyyy-MM-dd"` if you want to have default formatting.

If your view is written in HTML or XAML do it there using the same formatting technique.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your field on the database is `DateTime`. If you want to store just date, you should have a field with date data type. In this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#DateandTimeDataTypes), you can see the difference between the date data types.